# How to use "have resonance with"?

Tags: expressions

If I want to say "have the same feeling with ..." or "agree with ...", can I use "have resonance with ..."? For example, I knew a friend who doesn't own a cellphone and I found an article saying how great it is not having a cellphone. When I send this article to that friend, can I say "you may have resonance with this article"?

I found some people use this expression, but I'm not sure it is commonly used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word does work in this context, although an action verb like *feel* would probably be more effective than *have*.

A more concise option that avoids the need for "have" or "feel": "This article may resonate with you."

Comment: +1 for mentioning resonate. Another option that may work here is _relate to_.